# Loop over different Dataframes Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

**Hello World,**

I have 52 dataframes (df and data) with each of them containing only Name with first letter of Alphabet.

Below is an example for letter A & B (containing in df and data)

```
dfA                                                 dfB
Code  Name                                          Code  Name
15    Amiks                                         68    Bernard 
157   Alis                                          14    Barpti

dataA                                               dataB
Code  Name                                          Code  Name 
      Amiks                                               Berti
      Alis                                                Bernard
      Anatole                                             Barpti
```

**Question:**

Not an expert in Python, How can I loop over dataframes with the same letter? and not looking for all dataframes but just the same letter.

For Eg: Check whether:

- dataA.Name is in dfA.Name ?
- dataB.Name is in dfB.Name ?
- dataZ.Name is in dfZ.Name ?

## Edit

The original DF are below

```
df                                                 data
Code  Name                                          Code  Name
15    Amiks                                               Amiks   
157   Alis                                                Alis
14    Barpti                                             Bernard 
68    Bernard                                            Barpti
```

I just created one df per first letter.

The aim is to speed up the computational time and avoid checking within the whole DF, when we can check for only rows with the same first letter.

Thanks for anyone helping.

Comment: you can do something like: `for letter in ['A', 'B', 'Z']: print(globals()["df{}".format(letter)]);  print(globals()["data{}".format(letter)])`, but I would highly recommend using a dictionary to store 52 dataframes instead of 52 variables

Comment: Curious, how did you even get 52 data frames in global environment? With 52 separate `DataFrame` or `read_csv` calls? Consider **one** data frame with letter indicator.

Comment: @Parfait  Edited with your question

Comment: @Annis15 I suggest you keep your original dataframes and create a "letter" column: `df['letter'] = df['Name'].str[0]`. You can then filter your larger DataFrame on this column if you need to, e.g. `df[df['letter'].eq('A')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might be interested, below is what I have done:

**Step 1: re-merge all df's and data's.**

The output is :

- Df (containing all letters)
- Data (containing all letters)

**Step 2: Retrieve First letter of Name**

```
 # Function to retrieve first letter
    def first_letter(data, col):
        a= data[col].map(lambda x: x[0])
        b= np.unique(a)
        c= b.tolist()
        return c
```

**Step 3: Loop over DF and Data**

Compare only Name for which first letter is the same

```
# Apply function to retrieve unique first letter of Name's column and UV
first= first_letter(df, 'Name')

# Loop over each first letter to apply the matching by starting with the same letter for both DF
for letter in first:
    df_first= df[df['Name'].str.startswith(letter)]
    data_first= data[data['Name'].str.startswith(letter)]

# Process
....
```

With this code, I can match Names only for those who have the same first letter and not looking into the whole DF.

Answer (score 0):

You should considere variable names as only meaningful for you and not for the Python interpretor. Of course, there are hacky ways using `locals()` or `globals()` but they should never be used in *normal* code.

That means that is your dataframes are related, you should use a data structure to trace the relation. You could use 2 lists or a list of pairs, for example:

```
dataframes = [ (dfA, dataA), (dfB, dataB), ...]
```

If the letter itself matter, you could use a dictionary:

```
dataframes = { 'A': (dfA, dataA), 'B': (dfB, dataB), ...}
```

Then you can easily iterate:

```
for letter in dataframes:
    commons = dataframes[letter][0].merge(dataframes[letter][1], on='Name',
                                          suffixes=('_x', ''))[['Code', 'Name']]
    # process commons which contains code and name where datax.Name is in dfx.Name
    ...
```

---

But unless the original dataframe is really huge, I would suggest you to benchmark the one single dataframe with first letter way against the 52 dataframes one. Pandas if rather efficient provided everything fits in memory...